# PHP Imagick API - Translate CLI command to IMagick API

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to change the imagemagick exec commands in this method to IMagick php commands:

```
 public function colortone($input, $color, $level, $type = 0)
 {
    $args[0] = $level;
    $args[1] = 100 - $level;
    $negate = $type == 0? '-negate': '';

    $this->execute("convert 
    {$input} 
    ( -clone 0 -fill '$color' -colorize 100% ) 
    ( -clone 0 -colorspace gray $negate ) 
    -compose blend -define compose:args=$args[0],$args[1] -composite 
    {$input}");
}
```

For context, this method is taken from this nettuts tutorial on creating instagram iamge filters: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-instagram-filters-with-php--net-24504

I've been banging my head against a brick wall for a day now, I just can't seem to get it to work. I am not good with understanding how images manipulation works, and this could be my failing as I don't really understand what is being done in the first place to be able to transpose it to PHP.

This is what I've come up with...

```
public function colortone( $color, $level, $type = 0){
    $args[0] = $level;
    $args[1] = 100 - $level;
    $this->_image = new Imagick();
    $this->_image->setOption( 'compose:args', $args[0] . 'x' . $args[1] );
    $this->_image->readImage( $image_loc );


    $negate = $type == 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;

    $this->_image->setImageColorspace ( Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB ); 
    $_image_clone_1 = clone $this->_image; 
    $_image_clone_1 = $this->colorizeIt( $_image_clone_1, $color, 1.0 );

    $_image_clone_2 = clone $this->_image; 
    $_image_clone_2->setImageColorspace( Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY );
    if( $negate )
        $_image_clone_2->negateImage( 0 );

    $this->_image->compositeImage( $_image_clone_1, Imagick::COMPOSITE_BLEND, 0, 0 );
    $this->_image->compositeImage( $_image_clone_2, Imagick::COMPOSITE_BLEND, 0, 0 );
}
```

Here is the colorizeIt method being used above ( as it seems that the colorizeImage native IMagick method is a bit bust )

```
public function colorizeIt( $image_obj, $color, $alpha = 1 ){
    $draw = new ImagickDraw();
    $draw->setFillColor($color);

    if (is_float($alpha))
        $draw->setFillAlpha($alpha);        

    $geometry = $image_obj->getImageGeometry();
    $width = $geometry['width'];
    $height = $geometry['height'];

    $draw->rectangle(0, 0, $width, $height);

    $image_obj->drawImage($draw);
    return $image_obj;
}
```

Here is the original image, followed by the desired result and the actual result my PHP code is giving me:

[image: Original Image]

[image: Desired Result]

[image: And what I'm getting...]

As you can see, something is well and truly borked. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can add `+write file` in the middle of an IM command like this, so you can compare your interim images from the commandline with the PHP-generated images... `convert image.jpg \( + clone -colorspace gray +write temp1.png \) \( +clone ... +write temp2.png...`

Comment: Your `args` parameters look wrong... why do you assign to `$args[0]` and `$args[1]` AFTER you use `$arg1` and `$arg2` in `setOption()` - and then never use them again?

Comment: The code shown here is out of context, and I edited so it would make sense. Forgot about the args - will fix that now.

Comment: I cant seem to access Convert via the CLI. Doesn't look like Imagemagick is installed on the server - although it is available via PHP - I find this confusing. I dont have access to install on the server by the way.

Comment: What value are you passing for `$color`?

Comment: I'm passing in '#330000'

Comment: And value of `$level` ?

Comment: $level of 100, and $type = 0

Answer (score 1):

I have taken your command-line version and put in the parameters as I believe your code will create them, to give this command:

```
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqWqd.jpg         \
    \( -clone 0 -fill "#330000" -colorize 100% \)  \
    \( -clone 0 -colorspace gray -negate \)        \
    -compose blend -define compose:args=100x0 -composite output.jpg
```

and the result is this:

[image]

Version: ImageMagick 6.9.0-3 Q16 x86_64 2015-01-15 http://www.imagemagick.org

Comment: Thanks Mark, helps to have a baseline.